# Какие могут быть проблемы при возвращении ссылки на локальный указатель функции?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Чем возвращение локального указателя по ссылке:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int*& foo()
{
    int* pointer = new int{ 10 };
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int* point = foo();
}
```

Отличается от возвращения копии этого указателя:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* foo()
{
    int* pointer = new int{ 10 };
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int* point = foo();
}
```

Comment: Возвращать ссылку на локальную переменную -нельзя. Неважно указатель это или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае `int* foo()` возвращается *значение*, хранящееся в переменной; судьба самой переменной ни на что не влияет и никого не интересует — это копия значения, которое после завершения функции исчезает вместе с переменной.

В случае `int*& foo()` возвращается *ссылка* на переменную, по сути — ее адрес (по крайней мере я не знаю компиляторов, где это не так), и чтобы получить само значение указателя, надо разыменовать возвращенный указатель. Указатель на что? На переменную, которой *уже нет*. Ее время жизни завершилось вместе с функцией, место в памяти, где она была, уже может быть чем-то перезаписано.

`int*& foo()` *в этом смысле* аналог `int** foo()`. С последней функцией вам понятно, в чем проблемы?